# Pandas resample apply function on whole rows?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time

Is it somehow possible to get the rows of a resample operation to apply a custom function:

Let's assume we have a DataFrame `df` that contains for instance birthdays of children and their names and the number of friends they have:

```
birthday    name   friends
datetime_1  Alice  10
datetime_2  Bob    5
   ...      ...    ...
datetime_n  Tom    12
```

If we now resample by some time frequency and try to apply a custom function:

```
df.resample("w").apply(my_func)
```

It will only pass the input as separate series and not as rows. There is no `axis` argument in the case of `Resampler.apply`. So would there be any way to achieve something like I want. Or is there another built-in way that could be used to build custom behaviour into the reduction part? For example if I would want to return the most frequent name weighted by the number of friends that name is associated with in a given time interval.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, ok. What you need is grouper to be able to use groupby.

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W')).apply(my_func)
```

Hope, that's it.

Comment: Of course, but I want to use information across the row, thus I want to calculate something based on multiple columns of a given row. Was just wondering if it is possible, I have a solution based on preprocessing the necessary information into an object and then doing the apply but that is hacky and I was not certain it was actually necessary.